# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found on classpath while starting spark sql and thrift server

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, mysql-connector

I am receiving the following errors on starting the spark-sql shell.

But when I start the shell using the command it works

```
./spark-sql --jars /usr/local/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

But when I start the thrift server in the same way using below comamnd it throws the same error again.

```
/usr/local/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --jars /usr/local/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Please help me in understanding how this can be resolved so that I dont have to pass the jar path externally and why is it working for the spark-sql case and not with thrift server. Do I need to set classpath somewhere that I am missing ?

Please let me know if you need anything else.

```
 5/10/18 05:15:33 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
    15/10/18 05:15:33 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:47703
    15/10/18 05:15:33 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 47703.
    15/10/18 05:15:33 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.12:4040
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/local/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar at http://192.168.1.12:47703/jars/mysql-connector-java.jar with timestamp 1445125538564
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.1.12:7077/user/Master...
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20151018051538-0018
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20151018051538-0018/0 on worker-20151018024224-192.168.1.12-50211 (192.168.1.12:50211) with 4 cores
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20151018051538-0018/0 on hostPort 192.168.1.12:50211 with 4 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20151018051538-0018/0 is now LOADING
    15/10/18 05:15:38 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20151018051538-0018/0 is now RUNNING
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 43460.
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 43460
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.12:43460 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.12, 43460)
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
    15/10/18 05:15:39 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
    15/10/18 05:15:40 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
    15/10/18 05:15:40 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
    15/10/18 05:15:40 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
    15/10/18 05:15:40 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
    15/10/18 05:15:41 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
    15/10/18 05:15:41 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
    15/10/18 05:15:41 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
    15/10/18 05:15:41 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
    15/10/18 05:15:42 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@192.168.1.12:56227/user/Executor#-1120183734]) with ID 0
    15/10/18 05:15:42 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.12:34713 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.1.12, 34713)
    15/10/18 05:15:52 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
    15/10/18 05:15:52 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
    15/10/18 05:15:52 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: MySQL check failed, assuming we are not on mysql: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
    15/10/18 05:15:54 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
    15/10/18 05:15:54 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
    15/10/18 05:16:01 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
    15/10/18 05:16:01 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
    15/10/18 05:16:03 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
    15/10/18 05:16:04 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 0.13.1aa
    15/10/18 05:16:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
    15/10/18 05:16:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
    15/10/18 05:16:05 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
    15/10/18 05:16:05 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
    15/10/18 05:16:05 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
    15/10/18 05:16:05 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 0.13.1 using Spark classes.
    15/10/18 05:16:06 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
    15/10/18 05:16:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    15/10/18 05:16:06 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
    15/10/18 05:16:06 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
    15/10/18 05:16:07 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
    15/10/18 05:16:07 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
    15/10/18 05:16:07 WARN DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.liftedTree1$1(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.<init>(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
    NestedThrowables:
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "dbcp-builtin" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:85)
        ... 78 more
    Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DBCPBuiltinConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(DBCPBuiltinConnectionPoolFactory.java:49)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:238)
        ... 80 more
    15/10/18 05:16:07 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 12):

copy **mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar** to spark jars location in spark 2.x versions

```
$ cp -r $HIVE_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars/
```

Comment: For some reason --jars does not work, i guess we need to add --jars along with --driver-class-path, incase the jar is needed on the driver side as well, copying jar to the jars folder worked for me.

Comment: It works for me adding the jar to jars/ and then **restart** spark

Answer (score 5):

The main problem:
"Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient"

So in Hive lib you have copied mysql  connector. put that mysql class path in spark-env.sh file.

export SPARK_CLASSPATH="/home/hadoop/work/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
[image]

Finally Place hive-site.xml in spark conf folder. Now check this problem will resolve.

Comment: It worked for me after adding  the spark_classpath and hive-site.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try including jars in SPARK_CLASSPATH. You can update that spark-env.sh as well. Which version of spark you are using? Spark 1.3 and lower versions --jars has issues with adding JDBC drivers.

Comment: Spark 1.5.2 complains about use of SPARK_CLASSPATH:

15/12/22 08:36:31 WARN SparkConf: 
SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to '/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

Answer (score 0):

Add `SPARK_HOME` into your ~/.bash_profile file, like the following

```
# set spark directory
export SPARK_HOME=/var/www/python_project/extras/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Once you saved this file, Run the following command,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This saved my day :)

Hope this helps.